# MacBook Pro problem with screen freeze

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

My MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 worked perfectly, but last days it has many lags (screen freeze with or without artifacts/shaders). After force shutdown it beeps 3 times and after approximately 10 minutes it loads OS, but fan works very noisy and fast.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Did you change anything on the hardware side of things (new memory, new drives etc.) in the last days?

Comment: No, i didnt, but 3 years ago upgraded to 8GB RAM and SSD (replaced optical drive). It's left 3 years since this upgrade and everything was perfect. But now... By the way, CPU load is smth about 30% despite the opened VM (Ubuntu), chrome with n tabs, mail and development environtment :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Macbook air mid 2012 and it still runs like it is brand new. If I were you, I would get an external, backup everything you have on there. Do an internet recovery through disk utility and it should run like its brand new! Ive had issues like this before and what I suggested has been successful for me every time.

Answer (score -3):

After 3 years of use i will suggest to perform a format. You'll get a brand new Macbook pro in hours.

Comment: I haven't had to nuke & pave a Mac in 30 years... it's not Windows